# How to receive XmlDocument in MVC 4 Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmldocument

I am posting XmlDocument to ApiController (from windows service, service is working fine, it is posting correct, I used it in wcf web API), but XML is always null, what am I doing wrong?

I can post some class, such in tutorials, or Get any data and everything will be ok, but I can't post  XmlDocument.

```
public class XmlController : ApiController
{
    public void PostXml(XmlDocument xml)
    {
       // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

We need to use inheritance to inherit MediaTypeFormatter

```
public class XmlMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public XmlMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));      
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream stream,
         HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders,
         IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(s);

            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(xmlDoc);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
        }
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(XmlDocument);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then register it in Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostXml([FromBody] XmlDocument xml)
    {//code...}
```

Answer (score 2):

i follow the solution given by @Rhot but somehow it doesn't work so i edit like below which work for me:

```
public class XmlMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public XmlMediaTypeFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(XDocument);
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(XDocument);
        }

        public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream stream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string value = reader.ReadToEnd();            

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            try
            {
                var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(value);
                tcs.SetResult(xmlDoc);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //disable the exception and create custome error
                //tcs.SetException(ex);
                var xml = new XDocument(
                    new XElement("Error",
                        new XElement("Message", "An error has occurred."),
                        new XElement("ExceptionMessage", ex.Message)
                ));

                tcs.SetResult(xml);
            }

            return tcs.Task;
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(((XDocument)value).ToString());
            writer.Flush();

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            tcs.SetResult(null);
            return tcs.Task;
        }              
    }
```

register to global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

and below my WebAPI Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(XDocument xml)
        {            
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, xml);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `PostXml` supposed to be an action on a controller? If so you should mark your controller action as accepting an HttpPost. From there I would modify the action to work as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostXml(HttpPostedFileBase xml)
{
    // code
}
```

If you are still have trouble accepting the posted files, fire up the debugger and inspect the  Request files collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx

Comment: It's not mvc controller, it's apicontroller, and following this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations there's no necessity to add [HttpPost] attribute. Moreover xml is null too in your example.